# save <select> tag values for a specific using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a dynamic  tag on my website. The values of the tag are stored in my DB.
I want that the values of the tag to be shown just for a specific time which I pick up!, for example first value expires after 1 month and it will be not visible anymore. I have read about Cookies and Seesions, but the values are not realted to the login thats why I guess they are both not helpful here. Does anyobdy have a solution for this?, thanks a lot!!

```
// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); }

//get value for the dynamic list    
$sel_query="SELECT DISTINCT inhalt from aufgaben";
$res2=$conn->query($sel_query);
?>

<select name="dynamic_list"  autocomplete="off">
<option value="Aufgabe Auswählen" selected="selected"><h3> Aufgabe Auswählen</h3></option>

<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)) {
?>              

<option><?=$row["inhalt"];?></option>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Why not just do it by dates available if login is not relevant?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I thought about this, but how can i write a php code that says this value should be popped out of the list after a specific time. Nb: the list is dynamic and its getting the values from the DB.

Comment: If the date is greater than a certain time only show values having a certain key.

Comment: if you have a date value in your database in each row of aufgaben, your query can select only values greater than a given date:  SELECT DISTINCT inhalt FROM aufgaben WHERE datefield > cutoffdate

Comment: @fbas Yep i just added a date value to my DB, you saved my time by the querry. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @fbas I couldnt insert the date from the HTML input into the DB, can you take a look at my code?  `$time = strtotime($_POST['andate']);
   if ($time) {
    //reform the date to fit into the db
    $new_date = date('Y-m-d', $time); 
    $date_query= "INSERT INTO aufgaben(anlegdate) VALUES ('§new_date')" ;
    $res=$conn->query($date_query);
    
     // check whether the query has succeeded
     if (!$res) {
      echo "couldnt insert the date"; }
   } 
   else{
    echo 'Invalid Date: ' . $_POST['andate']; }
 } ` it never gets out of the "couldnt insert" message

Comment: My impressions is you want to UPDATE existing records, not insert into your db with that date.

Comment: @fbas do you know exactly what i should change to make the insert works ?, thanks!